# Changing the values in a binary matrix

Tags: r

Consider the 8 by 6 binary matrix, `M`:

```
M <- matrix(c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,
          0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
          0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
          0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,
          0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
          0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1),nrow = 8,ncol = 6)
```

Here is the `M`

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
[6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
[7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
[8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

The following matrix contains the column index of the `1`'s in matrix `M`

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    2    5    2    3    2
[2,]    4    3    6    4    4    3
[3,]    7    6    7    5    5    5
[4,]    8    7    8    7    6    8
```

Let's denote that

```
ind <- matrix(c(3,4,7,8,
                2,3,6,7,
                5,6,7,8,
                2,4,5,7,
                3,4,5,6,
                2,3,5,8),nrow = 4, ncol=6)
```

I'm trying to change a single position of `1` into `0`in each column of `M`.

For an example, one possibility of index of`1`s in each column would be `(4,2,5,4,3,2)`, `i.e.` `4th` position of Column1, `2nd` position of Column2, `5th`position of Column3 and so on. Let `N` be the resulting matrices. This will produce the following matrix `N`

```
N <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,
          0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
          0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,
          0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,
          0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1),nrow = 8,ncol = 6)
```

Here is that `N`

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
[6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
[7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
[8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

For **EACH** of the resulting matrices of `N`, I do the following calculations.

```
X <- cbind(c(rep(1,nrow(N))),N)
ans <- sum(diag(solve(t(X)%*%X)[-1,-1]))
```

Then, I want to obtain the matrix `N`, which produce the smallest value of `ans`. How do I do this efficiently?

Comment: What is `N` in the code?

Comment: One of the resulting matrices when you change 1's to 0's.

Comment: Could you show the expected output as it is not clear to me

Comment: how big is your real data ? in this case it seems like bruteforce would just need around 4000 iterations, that's not that much. Else it's more of a math problem, codewise I don't understand where is your challenge, you have a working solution that is too slow ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Sorry, I don't have a code. I'm trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this works.

We first build a conversion function that I'll need, and we build also the reverse function as you may need it at some point:

```
ind_to_M <- function(ind){
  M   <- matrix(rep(0,6*8),ncol=6)
  for(i in 1:ncol(ind)){M[ind[,i],i] <- 1}
  return(M)
}

M_to_ind <- function(M){apply(M==1,2,which)}
```

Then we will build a matrix of possible ways to ditch a value

```
all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value <- 1:4
for (i in 2:ncol(M)){
  all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value <- merge(all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value,1:4,by=NULL)
}
# there's probably a more elegant way to do that
head(all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value)
# x y.x y.y y.x y.y y 
# 1 1   1   1   1   1 1 # will be used to ditch the 1st value of ind for every column
# 2 2   1   1   1   1 1
# 3 3   1   1   1   1 1
# 4 4   1   1   1   1 1
# 5 1   2   1   1   1 1
# 6 2   2   1   1   1 1
```

Then we iterate through those, each time storing ans and N (as data is quite small overall).

```
ans_list <- list()
N_list   <- list()
for(j in 1:nrow(all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value)){
  #print(j)
  ind_N   <- matrix(rep(0,6*3),ncol=6)                            # initiate ind_N as an empty matrix
  for(i in 1:ncol(M)){
    ind_N[,i] <- ind[-all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value[j,i],i]    # fill with ind except for the value we ditch
  }
  N <- ind_to_M(ind_N)
  X <- cbind(c(rep(1,nrow(N))),N)
  ans_list[[j]] <- try(sum(diag(solve(t(X)%*%X)[-1,-1])),silent=TRUE) # some systems are not well defined, we'll just ignore the errors
  N_list[[j]] <- N
}
```

We finally retrieve the minimal ans and the relevant N

```
ans <- ans_list[[which.min(ans_list)]]
# [1] -3.60288e+15
N   <- N_list[[which.min(ans_list)]]
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    0    0    1    1
# [4,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
# [5,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
# [6,]    0    1    1    0    0    0
# [7,]    1    0    1    0    0    0
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

EDIT:

To get minimal positive ans

```
ans_list[which(!sapply(ans_list,is.numeric))] <- Inf
ans <- ans_list[[which.min(abs(unlist(ans_list)))]]
# [1] 3.3
N   <- N_list[[which.min(abs(unlist(ans_list)))]]
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    1    0    0
# [3,]    1    1    0    0    0    1
# [4,]    1    0    0    0    1    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
# [6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
# [7,]    1    0    1    1    0    0
# [8,]    0    0    1    0    0    1
```

EDIT 2 : to generalize the number of rows of ind to ditch

It seems to give the same result for ans for n_ditch = 1, and results make sense for n_ditch = 2

```
n_ditch <- 2
ditch_possibilities <- combn(1:4,n_ditch) # these are all the possible sets of indices to ditch for one given columns
all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value <- 1:ncol(ditch_possibilities) # this will be all the possible sets of indices of ditch_possibilities to test
for (i in 2:ncol(M)){
  all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value <- merge(all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value,1:ncol(ditch_possibilities),by=NULL)
}

ans_list <- list()
N_list   <- list()
for(j in 1:nrow(all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value)){
  #print(j)
  ind_N   <- matrix(rep(0,6*(4-n_ditch)),ncol=6)                            # initiate ind_N as an empty matrix
  for(i in 1:ncol(M)){
    ind_N[,i] <- ind[-ditch_possibilities[,all_possible_ways_to_ditch_value[j,i]],i]    # fill with ind except for the value we ditch
  }
  N <- ind_to_M(ind_N)
  X <- cbind(c(rep(1,nrow(N))),N)
  ans_list[[j]] <- try(sum(diag(solve(t(X)%*%X)[-1,-1])),silent=TRUE) # some systems are not well defined, we'll just ignore the errors
  N_list[[j]] <- N
}
```

Comment: note that pretty much all possible ans are positive (and below 19), so this negative solution may not be the one you need, tell me if you need the smallest positive solution and I'll update the code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wonder how come the 'ans' is negative.

Comment: What if want to change the two positions into zeros?

Comment: Well that'd be a different question... My code is currently designed to ditch a single value, I'd have to change it quite a bit. You want to be able to ditch n values, or you'll be good with 1 or 2 ? Maybe edit your question so it's as general as you need so we don't end up working for nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll check that too.

Comment: It seems there are more possibilities when we change two positions. There are 6 possibilities for each column and then total of 6^6 = 46656

Comment: there was a mistake, I left `1:4` in some place where it should have been `1:ncol(ditch_possibilities)` . see edit history to see where it was

Comment: Great. I'll check that.

Comment: That works perfectly. How do I do if I'm selecting two columns at a time and changing one 1 to 0? So I don't change all the columns at this time. I think there are 240 possibilities. I know I'm asking too much, but if you can help me on this that would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's much too different from the initial question now, I propose that you implement this solution, and if you can't find a way to solve your issue by yourself, post a new reproducible example

Comment: I just posted this as a new question.

Comment: Is it possible to have sample instead of all possibilities?