# Change the values in binary matrix only couple of columns

Tags: r

Consider the 8 by 6 binary matrix, `M`:

```
M <- matrix(c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,
          0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
          0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
          0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,
          0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
          0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1),nrow = 8,ncol = 6)
```

Here is the `M`

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
[6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
[7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
[8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

The following matrix contains the column index of the `1`'s in matrix `M`

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    2    5    2    3    2
[2,]    4    3    6    4    4    3
[3,]    7    6    7    5    5    5
[4,]    8    7    8    7    6    8
```

Let's denote that

```
ind <- matrix(c(3,4,7,8,
                2,3,6,7,
                5,6,7,8,
                2,4,5,7,
                3,4,5,6,
                2,3,5,8),nrow = 4, ncol=6)
```

I'm trying to change a single position of `1` into `0`only in SOME columns of `M`.
For an example, consider the case for changing two ones in every two columns. One possibility is given changing two positions in first two columns. Let N be the resulting matrices. This will produce the following matrix `N`

```
N <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,
              0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,
              0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
              0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,
              0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
              0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1),nrow = 8,ncol = 6)
```

Here is that `N`

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
[6,]    0    0    1    0    1    0
[7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
[8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

For **EACH** of the resulting matrices of `N`, I do the following calculations.

```
X <- cbind(c(rep(1,nrow(N))),N)
ans <- sum(diag(solve(t(X)%*%X)[-1,-1]))
```

Then, I want to obtain the matrix `N`, which produce the smallest value of `ans`.  This 8 by 6 matrix is just one example. How do I do this?

I asked a question similar to this one before which changes positions in every column. Here is the [link to that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406165/changing-the-values-in-a-binary-matrix).